# How do I define an R^4 function in Python where it's neccesary to distinguish between time and coordinates?

Tags: python, function

I need to define a function f(x,t,p) where x is a vector in R^2, t is time and p is a parameter in R. I need the function to understand that x is a vector, and t, p are reals. If I define the function as follows

```
def f(v,u,t,p):
    a=0.02
    b=0.2
    I=10.
    return (0.04*v^2+5*v+140-u+I, a*(b*v-u))
```

it doesn't distinguish between x=[v,u] and t,p. If I try to do the following

```
def f([v,u],t,p):
    a=0.02
    b=0.2
    I=10.
    return (0.04*v^2+5*v+140-u+I, a*(b*v-u))
```

it gives me syntax error. I have searched for a way to define a function that takes arrays and scalars but haven't found it.

PD: I know that t and p do not appear on the `return` sentence but it's absolutely nccesary to declare them in the entry parameters of the function.

Comment: The way you define a function f(x,t,p) is `def f(x,t,p):`.  You can then do `v, u = x` to split the vector into its components, or just use `x[0]` and `x[1]` to refer to them directly.  (What you tried with declaring `[v,u]` as a parameter worked back in Python 2.x, but there were some issues with this so the ability had to be removed.)

Answer (score 0):

The purest way to mimic vectors in Python is by using lists. You define a list by using brackets []. For example, the following list could symbolize a 2D vector.

```
vector_1 = [1, 1]
```

So now, in order to make sure that your functions takes a list/vector as an input you could do the following.

```
def f(x,t,p):
    
    if isinstance(x, list):
        v = x[0]
        u = x[1]
    else:
        raise ValueError("X must be a vector")
    a=0.02
    b=0.2
    I=10.
    return (0.04*v^2+5*v+140-u+I, a*(b*v-u))
```

By checking the type of x you make sure that a list/vector is provided otherwise you raise an appropriate error.